# How to set input box the same width as dropdown content using selectize.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, selectize.js

I'm using [Selectize.js](https://selectize.dev/) in my project to add searchable select controls.

For example

**HTML:**

```
<select placeholder="Choose an option..." class="selectize">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectize').selectize();
});
```

I want the option list to be the width of the largest element. I can achieve this with css

```
.selectize-dropdown {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

But then, how can I make the input box the same width as the option list?

I'm using this [fiddle](https://codepen.io/Azkamina/pen/XKrmzd) for tests (please ignore the css setting the width of div).

Comment: It looks to me both input and dropdown are as wide as the exampleSearch div. I think you do not need the extra css on .selectize-dropdown.

Comment: @HansDash ok sorry, forget about that css setting the size of exampleSearch. I need the select control to be the width of the largest element.